# Google Fonts некорректно отображается на Android - с примером

Tags: android, шрифты, google-fonts

Столкнулась со странной штукой — сайт на WordPress, в теме — Гуглошрифты. Для отображения текста требуется Garamond. На сайте — всё прекрасно. На телефонах на Android 6.0 — категорически не отображается. Не помогли ни отдельные прописывания в CSS, ни `!important`.

Может, есть какой-то хитрый костыль для адаптации шрифта под  Android?
Вот все прописанные правила:
Отдельно для шрифта

```css
/*Отдельно в CSS для конкретной страницы*/
    body {
    font-family: Garamond !important;
}
/*Отдельно для мобильного*/
    @media (max-width: 425px){
.twotext p{font-family: Garamond !important;}
}
```

```html
/*Отдельно для шрифта*/
<p style="color: #376574; font-family: Garamond; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;"></p>
```

Это кроме того, что еще он прописан в общих генеральных настройках темы))
По факту Андроид 6.0:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на сайте тем временем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера вряд ли сможем помочь

Comment: Пример добавила, понимаю, что тяжело вслепую))